# how to create empty file in python

Tags: python

I would like to create an empty file in Python. But I have difficulty creating one..Below is the Python code I used to create but it gives me error:

```
gdsfile  = "/home/hha/temp.gds"
if not (os.path.isfile(gdsfile)):
    os.system(touch gdsfile)
```

Error I got:
 File "/home/hha/bin/test.py", line 29
    os.system(touch gdsfile)
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

But from the command line, I am able to create new file using: touch

Thank you very much for your help
Howard

Comment: The argument to `os.system` needs to be a string.  That's not what you're passing right now.  Also, there's no reason to call out to the `touch` command when you could just use Python's own `open` method.

Answer (score 8):

First you have a syntax error because `os.system()` expects a string argument and you have not provided one. This will fix your code:

```
os.system('touch {}'.format(gdsfile))
```

which constructs a string and passes it to `os.system()`.

But a better way (in Python >= 3.3) is to simply open the file using the [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) builtin:

```
gdsfile  = "/home/hha/temp.gds"
try:
   open(gdsfile, 'x')
except FileExistsError:
   pass
```

This specifies mode `x` which means exclusive creation - the operation will fail if the file already exists, but create it if it does not.

This is safer than using `os.path.isfile()` followed by `open()` because it avoids the potential race condition where the file might be created by another process in between the check and the create.

---

If you are using Python 2, or an earlier version of Python 3, you can use [`os.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.open) to open the file with the exclusive flag.

```
import os
import errno

gdsfile  = "/home/hha/temp.gds"
try:
    os.close(os.open(gdsfile, os.O_CREAT|os.O_EXCL))
except OSError as exc:
    if exc.errno != errno.EEXIST:
        raise
```

Comment: I suggest adding the 'with' in front of the 'open', so that it will automatically clean up the returned file handle, e.g. ' with open(gdsfile, 'x') as touched_file: pass'

Comment: ``` with open(file_name, 'a') as f:
            pass ```